# Need help structuring an SQL query to retrieve record from a Postgres db (Rails app)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails (4.1.8) with Postgres (0.18.3).  Relevant to this question are three associated models in my application:

```
Member.rb
has_many :fitness_measurements, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :fitness_goals, :dependent => :destroy 

Fitness_Measurement.rb
belongs_to :member

Fitness_Goal.rb
belongs_to :member
```

The member_id "foreign key" is in the Fitness Measurements and Fitness Goals tables.

Here's the scenario:  I have a logged in "member".  Fitness measurements and fitness goals are both scoped to the member.  Before a member creates a new fitness goal I want to show that's member's most recent body measurements. In other words, I need to retrieve that member's last recorded fitness measurement and display data from that record on the form (Fitness Goal's form.html.erb).  I am able to retrieve the desired values when I know the id of the fitness measurement record.  For example, I get the desired values into the form view when I put this code in fitness_goals_controller.rb

```
before_action :get_fitness_measurement

private

def get_fitness_measurement  
  @fitness_measurement = @member.fitness_measurements.find(2)
end
```

Here's the relevant code in the form to create a new Fitness Goal (form.html.erb):

```
<p>
   <li><b>Current Weight:</b>  <%= @fitness_measurement.weight %></li><br> 
</p>
```

Of course the problem is I won't always know the id of the fitness measurement to retrieve.  I need help constructing a query to retrieve the last fitness measurement of the logged in member. That's the record I need to pull from the Fitness Measurements table. How do I structure such a query?  I read the documentation for Active Record Query Interface, but still can't figure out how to properly structure the necessary query.

In the Rails console, I ran the following queries:

```
@fitness_measurement = FitnessMeasurement.all
```

retrieves all fitness measurements in the database. Note:  the correct member ids are included.

```
@fitness_measurement = FitnessMeasurement.select('DISTINCT ON (member_id) *').order('member_id')
```

retrieves all fitness measurements orded by member id

```
@fitness_measurement = FitnessMeasurement.first
```

retrieves the first fitness measurement, which happens to belong to the logged in member.

```
@fitness_measurement = FitnessMeasurement.last
```

which retrieves the last fitness measurement recorded, which belongs to an anonymous member

I need to find the last Fitness Measurement which has the id of the logged in member.  How do I structure a query to retrieve that specific record from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could order a Member's fitness measurements by the time they were created and pick the last one.

```
@fitness_measurement = @member.fitness_measurements.order(:created_at).last
```

You will get nil if they don't have any measurements.

Comment: Thank you!  Your suggestion appears to solve the issue as I'm able to retrieve the desired records from the db. Good point about nil. I'll include a nil guard in the form; an if/else statement, something like <% if !@member.fitness_measurements.empty? %>  Thanks again for your help; I will mark your answer as accepted.